# Trouble calling a method from another class

Tags: java, class, object, methods

Below is my class file Rectangle and the class file testRectangle with the main method. Now in testRectangle when I call on the method "perimeter" in the class "Rectangle", I receive an error message. The error message I receive states, "Change modifier of 'perimeter()' to  'static'. The method can't be static because I will have several different rectangle objects in the main method. Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## Rectangle.java

```
public class Rectangle {
    private  int length;
    private  int width;

    Rectangle(int len, int wid) {
        length = len;
        width = wid;
    }
    public int perimeter(Rectangle rec){
        int p = 2*length + 2* width;
        return p;
    }
}
```

## testRectangle.java

```
    public class testRectangle {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(5,4);
            int r1Perimeter = Rectangle.perimeter(r1);
 //the line above this is where I get the error message
 //the red squiggly line goes under "Rectangle.perimeter(r1);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are calling it like it is a class method when it is only an instance method. Instead of `Rectangle.perimeter` it should be `r1.perimeter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call that method on an object of Rectangle. Because, `perimeter()` is an instance method, so you have to call on an instance.

If `perimeter()` is a static method, then you can call it with Class, like `Rectangle.perimeter(r1);`

```
int r1Perimeter = r1.perimeter(r1);
```

And there is no need to pass the `Rectangle` object there, define `perimeter()` method like below

```
public int perimeter(){
   int p = 2*length + 2* width;
   return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Rectangle.perimeter`, where `Rectangle` is a class, it's only allowed if `perimeter` is a *static* method.

But the problem here is in how you defined `perimeter`:

```
public int perimeter(Rectangle rec){
```

You really want this to be an instance method, because you want it to work on on an instance of `Rectangle`.  So you really don't want to include a `Rectangle` parameter.  In fact, your code body never uses `rec`, so the parameter here is wasted.  You should change it to

```
public int perimeter() {
    ...
}
```

and then the call `Rectangle.perimeter(r1)` becomes `r1.perimeter()`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call a class method, in this case `perimeter()`, the compiler needs to know which 'rectangle' you are referring to. If you were simply to refer to `Rectangle.perimeter()`, you are not specifying *which* rectangle, so the compiler becomes confused. Once you create a rectangle `Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(5,4)`, you have to let the compiler know that you are getting the perimeter of triangle *r1*. To do this you must call `r1.perimeter()`.

Essentially, when you define a method to a class, a pointer `this` to the object is passed along with it so that the compiler knows which specific Rectangle instance you are referring to.

If, on the other hand, you really wanted to call a method with `Rectangle.perimeter()`, then you would be referring to a method that would be the same for *every* rectangle. For example, you could create a method called `getNumSides()`, where no matter the rectangle, the value will always be the same. To do this you must declare it with `static`, meaning that the `this` pointer is no longer passed when the method is called. The method would be declared with `public static int getNumSides()` and would be called with `Rectangle.getNumSides()`.